# How to define base class arguments based upon child class type in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, inheritance, abstract-class

## Parent Class: `class Body(object)`

I have a parent class characterising the classical mechanics definition of a physical body. Such as it is, this parent class has the attributes: **name**, **mass**, **position**, **velocity**.

```
from Utilities import *

class Body(object):

  '''
  In classical mechanics a physical body is collection of
  matter having properties including mass, velocity, momentum
  and energy. The matter exists in a volume of three-dimensional
  space called its extension.
  '''

  def __init__(self, name, mass):
    if isinstance(name, str) and isinstance(mass, float):
      #Name
      self.name = name
      #Mass
      self.mass = mass
      #Position record
      self.positions = np.empty(shape = (0, 3), dtype = float)
      #Velocity record
      self.velocities = np.empty(shape = (0, 3), dtype = float)
      pass
    else:
      raise TypeError('Name and mass must be string and float, respectivly.')
    return None
```

## Child Class: `class Planet(Body)`

Additionally, I have a child class characterising Planets, which are fundamentally physical bodies, and thus should inherit the abstract physical attributes of such, namely: **name**, **mass**, **position**, **velocity**.

```
class Planet(Body):
  def __init__(self, name, mass = float):
    self.mass = Planet_Mass(name)
    Body.__init__(self, name, self.mass)
```

## Usage

```
#Import the necesary modules
from context import Planet
#Instantiate Earth as a massive celestial object
Earth = Planet('Earth')
#Print the mass of the planet [10^24 kg]
print 'The mass of Earth is: ', Earth.mass, ' [10^24 kg]'
```

### Result

`The mass of Earth is:  5.97  [10^24 kg]`

## Problem

Fundamentally, all physical bodies have **mass**. However, in the context of this simulation, the method by which **mass** is determined differs between the various child classes of `class Body(object)`, namely: `class Planet(Body)`, `class Satellite(Body)`, etc.

- In `class Planet(Body)`, **mass** is determined via `Planet_Mass(name)`, which involves reading through a planetary fact sheet .txt file.
- In `class Satellite(Body)`, **mass** is determined via `Satellite_Mass(name)`, which involves reading through a satellite fact sheet .txt file.

**Is there anyway to alter the initialisation of my child classes to be less redundant?**

Essentially, I would like to remove the necessity of stating `self.mass = Planet_Mass(name)` in `class Planet(Body)`.

Comment: Implement class methods for the children, they should all `__init__` with the calculated mass.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So you're saying that I should invoke `mass = Planet_Mass(name)` before `def __init__(self, name, mass)`? That will not work, as `name` will not be defined yet.

Comment: Code doesn't work out in comments. Just google for alternate constructors in Python using class methods.

Answer (score 3):

Don't accept `mass` in your Planet class constructor since you're not going to use it.

Don't set `self.mass` in your Planet class constructor since the parent constructor does it.

```
class Planet(Body):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Body.__init__(self, name, Planet_Mass(name))
```

If you do want to accept `mass` in your Planet class and allow it to *override* the mass from the lookup table (or maybe some planets aren't in the lookup table), do it like this:

```
class Planet(Body):
    def __init__(self, name, mass=None):
        if mass is None:
            Body.__init__(self, name, Planet_Mass(name))
        else:
            Body.__init__(self, name, mass)

earth   = Planet("Earth")
trantor = Planet("Trantor", 1.792e25)   # Asimov's Trantor; ~3x Earth mass
```

If you want to go further and avoid the `if` statement in your subclasses' `__init__` then you can put the desired behavior on the `Body` class. The basic idea is that you define a method to calculate the mass from the name. On the base class, this method would do nothing. On your subclasses, it gets the mass from the lookup table. Then you don't even need `__init__` in your subclasses.

```
class Body(object):

     def __init__(self, name, mass=None):
         if mass is None:
             mass = self._name2mass(name)
         # followed by the argument checking and attribute setting
         # especially, you must check that mass is not None

     @staticmethod
     def _name2mass(name): return None

class Planet(Body):

     @staticmethod
     def _name2mass(name): return Planet_Mass(name)
     # or just implement Planet_Mass here!
```

I've used `@staticmethod` because looking up a body's mass by its name does not require access to the instance (or the class, for that matter).

Comment: Yes, I just came to your first solution. However, I do like your second solution for user manipulability. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Your solution works. However, is there anyway to avoid questioning whether mass is specified or not for each child class?

Comment: Yes, I've added an example of that.

Comment: This works, but I want to keep `_name2mass(name)` invisible.

Comment: You can't make things "invisible" in Python.